# Moving geometry at same distance in different coordinate systems

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, distance, coordinates

I haven't been making tools in ArcPy for a while and stuck in one case.

My goal is to create a serie of geometries in a center of current extent by running a script. I.e when I move ArcMap's extent and press a custom tool button, four points at certain distances between each other and one polyline are added to specific layers in a center of extent. This is made for saving time when cartographer has to digitize same shapes multiple times.

The algorithm seems to be pretty simple:

1. Find the center coordinate of current extent
2. Create multiple points changing only X coordinate of each new point by adding float numbers of distances in meters
3. Create line between first and last points
4. Add geometries to layers.

As a result a plain horizontal line with four points should appear in layers and ArcMap's workspace. Something like that:

[image]

But other users can set another coordinate system in dataframe and in this case a center of extent can be a coordinate containing decimal degrees or meters. Script can add fixed decimal values to an degree-X coordinate of extent's center and finally distances can be completely different while I need a strict metrical distances in any coordinate system.

I tried to transform dataframe's extent with `.projectAs()` method and got a center coordinate in Equidistant projection. Then performed calculations for center point, generated geometries and projected them to inital dataframe's coordinate system with a same `.projectAs()` method.

Unfortunately if I change dataframe's settings by pointing another coordinate systems and run script the result will be different every time. I think there should be an easier solution rather then transforming geometries.

Here is a piece of code:

```
import arcpy

def get_center_coordinate(dataframe):
    ex = dataframe.extent.projectAs(arcpy.SpatialReference(check_crs))
    x_center = (ex.XMax + ex.XMin) / 2
    y_center = (ex.YMax + ex.YMin) / 2

    return (x_center, y_center)

# current dataframe data
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = mxd.activeDataFrame
init_sr = df.spatialReference

# metric crs
check_crs = 54027
check_crs_obj = arcpy.SpatialReference(check_crs)

# calculation of new coordinates and creating geometry objects
center_cor = get_center_coordinate(df)
pnt_leftmost = center_cor[0] - 1.145
pnt_gas = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(pnt_leftmost, center_cor[1]), check_crs_obj).projectAs(init_sr)
pnt_arm_first = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(pnt_leftmost + 0.29, center_cor[1]), check_crs_obj).projectAs(init_sr)
pnt_arm_second = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(pnt_leftmost + 0.59, center_cor[1]), check_crs_obj).projectAs(init_sr)
pnt_cross = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(pnt_leftmost + 2.29, center_cor[1]), check_crs_obj).projectAs(init_sr)
list_line_new = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(pnt_leftmost, center_cor[1]), arcpy.Point(pnt_leftmost + 2.29, center_cor[1])])
polyline_segment = arcpy.Polyline(list_line_new, check_crs_obj).projectAs(init_sr)

# making insert cursors
ic_gas = arcpy.da.InsertCursor('gas_pnt','SHAPE@') 
ic_arm = arcpy.da.InsertCursor('arm_pnt','SHAPE@') 
ic_cross = arcpy.da.InsertCursor('cross_pnt','SHAPE@') 
ic_segments = arcpy.da.InsertCursor('segments','SHAPE@') 

# adding geomtries to layers
ic_gas.insertRow([pnt_gas]) 
ic_arm.insertRow([pnt_arm_first]) 
ic_arm.insertRow([pnt_arm_second]) 
ic_cross.insertRow([pnt_cross]) 
ic_segments.insertRow([polyline_segment]) 

del ic_gas, ic_arm, ic_cross, ic_segments
```

Comment: What does 'different every time' mean? I can see that you're instantiating cursors and deleting them but it would be better to use with blocks, just in case you forget to del later (eg with arcpy.da.InsertCursor('gas_pnt','SHAPE@') as ic_gas: ic_gas.insertRow([pnt_gas]) )

Comment: @MichaelStimson I meant that accoriding to different dataframe spatial references my new objects has different distanses between each other. I.e. I need a polyline with a length of 2.5 meters in any spatial reference.

Comment: That's the problem with projections, all of them are models and how they calculate distances is different in each model... none of them are really correct when compared to a site survey. You will also notice what 'flat' is differs also. What you have done in your code is wise, projecting to a specific spatial reference, it's as close as you're going to get to a standard, using EPSG:54027 should work for anywhere but you might want to choose a more local CRS for the country your data is in, the more local the less distortion.